# Как настроить ввод спецсимволов через Alt в линуксе?

Tags: linux, windows, клавиатура

В Windows можно вводить спецсимволы при помощи Alt и десятичного кода.
Например, чтобы ввести неразрывный пробел, надо нажать
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd></kbd>.

В линуксе есть аналогичная функциональность, но используется Ctrl+Shift+U и шестнадцатеричный код: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd><kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd></kbd>.

А можно ли перенастроить на виндоусовский вариант?
Точнее так: можно ли сделать, чтобы работали одновременно оба варианта?

PS: Linux Mint.

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать настроить `Alt` как [Compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Compose_key). Но это наверняка вызовет массу неудобств.

Лучше использовать стандартный (обычно это `Shift+AltGr`) и сделать список соответствующих комбинаций. Для этого нужно скопировать файл `/usr/share/X11/locale/<ваша локаль>/Compose` в `~/.XCompose` и отредактировать последний.

Этот способ более универсальный, поскольку `Ctrl+Shift+U` работает [не во всех приложениях](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_X11_.28Linux_and_other_Unix_variants.29).